# Stop YouTube Video on Back Button of Windows Metro App 8.1

Tags: windows-8, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml, winrt-async, winrt-xaml-toolkit

I have a page on which i am showing multiple youtube videos as webviews. When i play any video, then correspoding video starts playing. But When I click on the back button of the App i should be stop then but its running in background(can hear voice of video).

here is the code of back button:

```
protected void GoBack(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
        ((Frame)Window.Current.Content).GoBack();
}
```

Tell me how i can dispose of this webview or can stop video.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution:
Invoke the UnLoaded event of WebView
 - webView.Unloaded += webView_UnLoaded;

Then change the source of the webview in webView_UnLoaded event handler:
Here is my code:

```
private void webView_UnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        WebView webView = (WebView)sender;
        webView.Source = new Uri(" ");
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

First make sure that the page is finalized; most probably by detaching all the event handlers you manually attached before. Then (sooner or later) the page will be finalized which in turns disposes of the webview.

A similar effect would be achieved by forward navigating the webview to an empty html page.