# Problem with stopping video on back press in UWP

Tags: xaml, uwp, windows-10-universal

I have a UWP app with `NavigationView` that handles the backstack in different frames. The back press is handled in my `MainPage.xaml` by the function:

```
private bool On_BackRequested()
        {
            if (contentFrame.CanGoBack)
            {
                contentFrame.GoBack();
                Debug.WriteLine(contentFrame.);
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
```

But the problem arises when there is a `MediaPlayerElement` playing videos in a frame. The back press is handled properly but the video doesn't stop playing (I know this because the audio from the video is still playing in the background).

How can I stop the video playback during the back press method? Can I access a certain function from the childframe to stop the video?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution using [Stop YouTube Video on Back Button of Windows Metro App 8.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19270595/stop-youtube-video-on-back-button-of-windows-metro-app-8-1). I used an unloaded function in the constructor of the child frame.

```
mediaPlayer.Unloaded += mediaPlayer_UnLoaded;
```

And also added a function:

```
private void mediaPlayer_UnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            mediaPlayer.MediaPlayer.Pause();
        }
```